# Exclusions from condition on Select Ends

Tags: mysql

I Have this Query1:

```
"SELECT * FROM `MAIN_TAB` WHERE 

`REFERENCE` IN ('REFERENCE_A','REFERENCE_B','REFERENCE_C') AND 

`STATUS` NOT IN ('STATUS_A','STATUS_B') ORDER BY `REFERENCE` ASC"
```

But in the end of the Query1 i need an exclusion after the output of Query1 are colected ->

Something like this

```
`"WHERE `REFERENCE` = 'REFERENCE_B' AND ``USER`` NOT In
('JOE','BRIAN','ROGER')"`.
```

Maybe what that i want, be an Select inside other, or a condition inside the

```
`<`REFERENCE` IN ('REFERENCE_A','REFERENCE_B','REFERENCE_C')>`
```

... But i don't know how to get it.

Comment: Ok, understood .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you need this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   `main_tab`
WHERE  `status` NOT IN ( 'STATUS_A', 'STATUS_B' )
       AND ( `reference` IN ( 'REFERENCE_A', 'REFERENCE_C' )
              OR ( `reference` = 'REFERENCE_B'
                   AND `user` NOT IN ( 'JOE', 'BRIAN', 'ROGER' ) ) )
ORDER  BY `reference` ASC
```

Comment: @PepeLegal happy to help :)

Comment: Madhur, for sure!